# obtaining a fragment data file bed from bam

Tags: sam, bed, bedtools, wgs, epigenetics

Im trying to follow this pipeline https://github.com/epifluidlab/cragr on cfDNA WGS. I have bam files from paired end reads aligned with bwa mem.

The workflow requires bgzipped and indexed fragment data files as input.
[image]

I have been searching how can I obtain BED files from fragments coordinates instead of reads coordinates, and came up with no answer.

Does someone know how can I obtain such bed file?

Comment: Hi, what do you mean? :) I don't know how to do it. I'm familiar with bamtobed from bedtools but that gives me a bed file based on reads. I need a bed file based on fragments instead :)

Comment: I see so you are looking whether there is a bedtools option for fragment output. Got it, thanks. Would be good to modify the question with the info.

Answer (score 2):

There's an example in the README (https://github.com/epifluidlab/cragr#example-datasets):

> For you information, below are steps from the BAM file to the
> fragment file:

```
samtools sort -n -o qsorted.bam -@ 4 sample.bam
samtools view -h -f 3 -F 3852 -G 48 --incl-flags 48 qsorted.bam |\
  bamToBed -bedpe -mate1 -i stdin |\
  awk -F'\t' -v OFS="\t" '{if ($1!=$4) next; if ($9=="+") {s=$2;e=$6} else {s=$5;e=$3} if (e>s) print $1,s,e,$7,$8,$9}' |\
  sort -k1,1V -k2,2n |\
  bgzip > sample.frag.bed.gz
tabix -p bed sample.frag.bed.gz
```